# Why request without suffix of filename extension html will download file?

Tags: html, nginx, configuration

I want to test the nginx‘s echo module.And I want to echo the url of what I type in **browser**.

**My nginx  configuration：**

```
   index  index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html ;

   location / {               
       try_files $uri $uri/  /index.php  =404;              
   }
   location  /hello {
   echo $request_uri;
   }
```

---

input url : `http://127.0.0.1/hello/.`

return : **return a file** and the file have content : `/hello/`

---

input url: `http://127.0.0.1/hello/hi`

return : **return a file** and the file have content : `/hello/hi`

---

input url:`http://127.0.0.1/hello/hi.html`

return: **print** `/hello/hi.html` in **browser**.

---

**My question:**
Why the url without  the html suffix will become download file?
How to fix it ?
I just want to print the url in **browser**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nginx` determines the `Content-Type` from the extension. These are included from a file called `mime-types`. You can override this behaviour by placing a `default-type` directive in the `location` block. For example:

```
location  /hello {
    types {}
    default_type    text/html;
    echo $request_uri;
}
```

See [this doucument](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Whether browser would render the page/download file finally depends on other factors, for example, ['Content-type'](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) /['Content-Disposition'](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt)  in http header

```
Content-Disposition takes one of two values, `inline' and
`attachment'.  `Inline' indicates that the entity should be
immediately displayed to the user, whereas `attachment' means that
the user should take additional action to view the entity.
```

You may check and compare the http responses when visiting 
/hello/hi or /hello/hi.html, to examine that at least one of these two headers may not be correctly set, in this case it is more possibly content-type is not 'text/html' here

A solution would be specifying content-type for your path, may be like

```
location  /hello {
  default_type "text/html";
  echo $request_uri;
}
```

or

```
location  /hello {
  add_header  Content-Type 'text/javascript;charset=utf-8';
  echo $request_uri;
}
```