# How to get a "text/plain" output on a XSL transformed stylesheet with nginx?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, nginx

I'm trying to write XSL stylesheet to transform result into a simple plain text string, and I'm getting the following **error on Chrome and Opera**:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
>
> This document was created as the result of an XSL transformation. The
>   line and column numbers given are from the transformed result.

**while it works fine on Firefox**.

Why?

The XSL is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="rtmp"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rtmp">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="server"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="server">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="application"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="application">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="live"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="live">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="stream"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="stream">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="publishing"><xsl:value-of select="name"/>:<xsl:value-of select="nclients - 1"/>,
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the nginx conf is:

```
location /live {
    rtmp_stat all;
    rtmp_stat_stylesheet live.xsl;
    include mime.types;
    default_type text/plain;
}
location /live.xsl {
    root /usr/local/nginx/html/;
}
```

The purpose is actually to retrieve the result from [nginx RTMP module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module).

I opened up View Page Info on the Firefox page and the type is "text/xml". I think if I can make it appear as "text/plain" it would solve the problem. But how? Can I configure this in nginx or in the XSL stylesheet?

I'd like to receive a text/plain string with a 200 status.

Comment: may be you can try it https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218015/6229548

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the output of your stylesheet is a xml document and it can't start with text, so Opera and Chrome decide to complain.

Add a

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

to your stylesheet below the `<stylesheet>` element to declare the output as text.